# React-Native Android Error : Activity Class {<appName>/.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: runtime-error, react-native

In trying to build the React-Native application for Android after changing the package name manually; I encountered this error where the app failed to start because it could not find the "Main Activity" even though I was able to navigate to the file and view it.

As other answers have suggested, I verified the package identifier at the top of the file was accurate with the gradle build files as well as what is also found in the manifest file; and also insured the include ":app" is present in one of the build files.

None of these were the issue as everything had been updated accordingly.

Please see my answer below; as this is the solution that worked for ME, but there appears to be many points of failure as mentioned above, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question because it appears that there could be multiple causes of this issue but I did not see an answer with this solution, this solution did work for me.

`/ProjectFiles/android/app/src/main/java/com/oldAppName`

was the source of the problem, a folder name...
So the new folder name was as follows, and my applications main activity was able to be found at runtime:

`/ProjectFiles/android/app/src/main/java/com/<organization.appliction.android>`

<this is the pattern I used, I was unsure if the dots should be included, they are...>